# Randomly show 6 items form a list of 70 in bxslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I have a unique query when i implemented bxslider ( http://bxslider.com/ ) in a site.

I have tried searching for this but couldn't solve it.

I have pulled all the 70 items on the page and applied slider and is working completely. But is it possible to show only 6 random items in the slider from the list of 70.

I would surely appreciate your help.

```
<ul id="bx-slider-random">
<li>item item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
<li>item 4</li>
<li>item 5</li>
<li>item 6</li>
<li>item 7</li>
<li>item 8</li>
<li>item 9</li>
<li>item 10</li>
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
<li>item 70</li>
```

$j('#bx-slider-random').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true
});

I already got the 70 items fetched to the slider.
But need to know if i can directly show only random 6 items from all 70 items everytime the page is refreshed.

Thanks :)
Cheers...

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it possible. from a look to the source of page you should first get all 70 items, then choose some of them randomly and then put them in `<li>`'s.
finally you can call your box slider initialization.
if you had a sample code may be i can help you more specified!?

**here is your code**

```
var mindc = 0;
var maxdc = $('ul#bx-slider-random li').length;
for(var i=0; i<63; i++){
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxdc - mindc + 1)) + mindc;
    $('ul#bx-slider-random li').eq(randomIndex).remove();
}
$('#bx-slider-random').bxSlider({ auto: true, autoControls: true });
```

**edit**

this is little edited and simply worked in your fiddle(is there a need for noConflict ?):

```
var mindc = 0;
var maxdc = $('ul#bx-slider-random li').length;
alert(maxdc);
for(var i=0; i<19; i++){
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxdc - mindc + 1)) + mindc;
    $('ul#bx-slider-random li').eq(randomIndex).remove();
}
$('#bx-slider-random').bxSlider({ auto: true, autoControls: true });
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply...but still i m unable to get the solution...
http://jsfiddle.net/z9sHk/
i have created the jsfiddle example for the same...but couldnt solve it..if you can please create a same jsfiddle example..
thanks :)